# Transfer values from specific sheets of a workbook into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transfer values from specific sheets of a workbook to another sheet named database. However, my intention is to only copy the values not the formulas. I am getting

> run-time error 13 - type mismatch error.

What seems to be the problem.

```
Sub Button4_Click()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim wkSht As Worksheet
 Dim wsC As Worksheet
 Dim rowCount As Integer
 Dim nextEmptyRow As Integer

 Set wsC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
 For Each wkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    nextEmptyRow = wsC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If wkSht.Name <> "Database" And wkSht.Name <> "Combine" And wkSht.Name <> "CETIN" Then
        For i = 17 To 30
            If wkSht.Range("AY" & i).Value > 0 Then
                wkSht.Range("AY" & i).Value = wsC.Range("A" & nextEmptyRow).Value
                wkSht.Range("K" & i).Value = wsC.Range("B" & nextEmptyRow).Value
                wkSht.Range("R" & i).Value = wsC.Range("C" & nextEmptyRow).Value
                wkSht.Range("T" & i).Value = wsC.Range("D" & nextEmptyRow).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next wkSht
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? I would think you want to write `wsC.Range("A" & nextEmptRow).value = wkSht.Range("AY" & i).value`. With your code you are writing empty values of database-sheet to the other sheets

Comment: Is it possible that `nextEmptyRow` to exceed the `Integer` limit of `32767`. If so, you should declare it `Dim  nextEmptyRow As Long`. Anyhow, in VBA nothing is  saved in terms of memory allocation declaring variables as `Integer`. I would dare to suggest you cultivating the habit to always declare such variables `As Long`.

Comment: I am getting error in the following line "If wkSht.Range("AY" & i).Value > 0 Then"

Comment: Also no data seems to be transferred

Comment: Most likely `wkSht.Range("AY" & i).Value` returns a string when the error is thrown. As I already said: even if you don't get the error, no data will be transfered until you switch your "copy"-statements as I already suggested in my first comment

Comment: What is the value of `wkSht.Range("AY" & i).Value` when the error is thrown?